# how to change a text of element in a parent tag using xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to replace the element tag name using xslt. I have an output like this:

```
<gl-cor:documentInfo>
    <gl-cor:entriesType contextRef="journal_context">DocumentID</gl-cor:entriesType>
    <gl-cor:uniqueID contextRef="journal_context">RevisionID</gl-cor:uniqueID>
</gl-cor:documentInfo>
<gl-cor:entityInformation>
    <gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber>
        <gl-cor:phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">779633</gl-cor:phoneNumber>
    </gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber>
    <gl-cor:entityFaxNumberStructure>
        <gl-cor:entityFaxNumbercontextRef="journal_context">1234-56-89</gl-cor:entityFaxNumber>
    </gl-cor:entityFaxNumberStructure>
</gl-cor:entityInformation>
```

And, I want my output to be looks like this:

```
<gl-cor:documentInfo>
    <gl-cor:entriesType contextRef="journal_context">DocumentID</gl-cor:entriesType>
    <gl-bus:uniqueID contextRef="journal_context">RevisionID</gl-cor:uniqueID>
</gl-cor:documentInfo>
<gl-cor:entityInformation>
    <gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber>
        <gl-bus:phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">779633</gl-bus:phoneNumber>
    </gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber>
    <gl-bus:entityFaxNumberStructure>
        <gl-bus:entityFaxNumbercontextRef="journal_context">1234-56-89</gl-bus:entityFaxNumber>
    </gl-bus:entityFaxNumberStructure>
</gl-cor:entityInformation>
```

All the children of `<gl-cor:entityInformation>` should replace instead of gl-cor, it should be gl-bus. Is it possible to do this?

I tried to create a sample xslt but it didn't work. The error occurs in the `<gl-bus:phoneNumber>`, because I think it is contain a special characters? like "-" and ":".

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gl-cor:entityInformation/gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber/gl-cor:phoneNumber">
<gl-bus:phoneNumber>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</gl-bus:phoneNumber>
</xsl:template>
```

Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `gl-cor` and `gl-bus` are namespace prefixes. Namespace prefixes are written before an XML element and seperated from the XML element with a `:`. So your problem is not because of the characters `-` and `:`, these are all valid characters, please also read these articles/tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

To answer your problem we need to know what the namspace URIs are for `gl-cor` and `gl-bus`, but it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gl-cor="http://example.org/gl-cor" xmlns:gl-bus="http://example.org/gl-bus">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::gl-cor:entityInformation]">
        <xsl:element name="gl-bus:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template `*[ancestor::gl-cor:entityInformation]` will match on all (grand)children of `gl-cor:entityInformation`.

**NOTE**

The namespaces in the XSLT should be updated and match to your input XML:

```
xmlns:gl-cor="http://example.org/gl-cor"
xmlns:gl-bus="http://example.org/gl-bus"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already using your code and when I transform my xml output to xsl the error was pointing to this part: gl-bus:{local-name()}, and i don't know, what does it mean.

Comment: @hannah: Update your question and post more of your input XML, because you need to set the namespaces correct. Also gives us the exact error you receive.

Comment: woah!i forgot to change the namespaces in the xslt. And, yes!it's working fine. thank you so much.

Comment: @hannah: If the answer satifies your question don't forget to accept the answer. You can do this by clicking on the check button beside the answer.

Comment: I just notice that there is an attribute in the phoneNumber element: <br/>  <gl-cor:entityInformation>
  <gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber **xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12"**>
   <gl-bus:phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">779633</gl-bus:phoneNumber>
  </gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber>
 </gl-cor:entityInformation>  <br/>how can I remove the one with asterisks? thanks.

Comment: @hannah that is not an attribute that is the namespace declaration. You can't remove it because it is necessary when you put elements into that namespace.